# How to Drop 2 nested shadows On 2 Divisions in CSS?

Tags: html, css

i am using 3 divisions the first one is a header the second is the main division and the third is the last.i want the first division to drop a shadow on the second and i did it successfully,but also i want the main division to drop a shadow on the third "last" division but i CAN'T do it and here is the code :

HTML :-

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fadykamalcss.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header1">
    </div>

    <div id="main">
    </div>

    <div id="last">
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS :-

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

div#header1{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:#242d34;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px -6px black;
}

div#main{
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:#ffaa05;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px -6px black;
}

div#last{
    position:relative;
    z-index:-2
    margin-top: -700px;
    width:100%;
    height:400;
    background:#242d34;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on your z-index in the `#last` selection. Also, your `height` is missing a unit. http://jsfiddle.net/MYGh8/4/

Comment: oh yeah i fixed it,but still there is a problem the last division isn't visible,the shadow is visible but the last division isn't,why is that ?

Comment: Because you hide it with your `margin-top: -700px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems in your CSS
First you're missing a ; after your z-index
Second you're missing the "px" on height:400px;

Additionally, you won't see anything with the margin set to -700 (probably on purpose).
Here's a link to it so you can see it all:
http://jsfiddle.net/kEQVh/